# How to make char* kmers from an extremely long C++ string

Tags: c++, string, memory, char

I have a string object that is really long and I'd like to refer to windows in it [0, 19], [1, 20], .....,  [980, 1000] as `char x[20]`.

Let's call our string `foo`. I've tried

```
x = &foo[i]
```

and iterating, but I get an incompatible type error, because `&foo[i]` is of type `char *`.

How can I refer to that 20-char block of the memory of our string foo, using a `char x[20]`?

More philosophically, what is the difference between `char *x`, and `char x[20]` if the later is not null terminated?

One objective is not to have to have 2x the memory requirement by creating brand new memory blocks for all the new chars.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html) class from llvm.  Essentially, it just holds two pointers, a begin and an end.  You can do something like this, for example:

```
std::string source = "... something really long ...";
const char * b = source.c_str();
llvm::StringRef window(b + 100, 20);
```

`window` is now an entity that refers to a portion of `source`.  You can call `begin()` and `end()` on it to get iterators.  You can print it just like a normal string, like this:

```
std::cout << window;
```

It comes with a variety of other common string operations as you can see in the [docs](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I need the type to be char * or char x [20]

Comment: @Deniz: There is a member function, 'data()' that gives you a const char *.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I believe this doesn't accomplish the goal; because when I use "data()", does the pointer / memory block persist?  The idea is to be able to pass a char * into a function as a pointer to my more persistent long string, but only the first 20 characters, in a window.  Might be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

`char * p` is a pointer to memory somewhere that should contain characters. There is no end of data implied.
`char a[100]` is a 100 character section of memory. The end of a is known to the compiler to access multi-dimensional arrays and for error checking function parameters.
&a[0]  or just  a  (address of element 0 of a) is basically the same as char*.

The user of a or p must know the length somehow:

1) a length parameter supplied in addition. Ex: `sizeof(a)` (which is in bytes).
I also like to use `numof(a)` which is could of elements instead of byte size by adding:
`#define numof(X)  (sizeof(X)/sizeof(*X))`
Instead of length, you can also use another pointer to the end to stop at.

2) some content or rule that tells the user of p when to stop. Ex: `*p == 0`  (NULL)

This a powerful source of flexibility in C/C++ (and also danger if misused).

---

a) Change user of array to also have a length limit or pointer to end to stop at.
You may also need null termination checking in case the last block is undersized.

b) Process data only one block at a time. Then you only new 1 additional 20 char array.
Or, if you can assure no other threads are using the array at the same time, you can temporarily change the null termination:

```
// array is assumed to be a multiple of 20 plus 1 more for null
char * ptr = array;
while ( ptr < array + sizeof(array)-1 )
{
  char * end = ptr + 20; // we will stop here
  char save_char = *end; // save the character there
  *end = 0; // put in temporary null
  ProcessBlock( ptr ); // now null terminated !
  *end = save_char; // restore the array
  ptr = end; // end of this block is start of next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
int window_size = 20;
for (size_t i = 0; i < foo.size() - window_size; ++i)
{
    const char* x = foo.data() + i;
    // Do something with x[0] to x[window_size - 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting the "incompatible type error" is that `x` and `&foo[i]` are of different types. Consider this:

- `foo` is of type `char[]` (i.e. array of `char`)
- therefore `foo[i]` is of type `char`
- therefore `&foo[i]` is of type `char*` (i.e. pointer to `char`)

The difference between `char* x` and `char x[20]` is that in the first case `x` is a pointer to char and in the second case it is an array of `char`. In the first case you may make the pointer point at any `char` in your process' memory. In the second, `x` can often behave like a pointer, but it always points at the beginning of the array.

Assuming foo size is a multiple of window size, you can iterate through the windows like this:

```
char foo[FOO_SIZE];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < FOO_SIZE; i += WINDOW_SIZE) {
    char first_char = foo[i];
    char last_char = foo[i + WINDOW_SIZE - 1]; // Warning: if foo size is not multiple of window size, this may exceed foo in the last window
}
```

Also, your own code is probably fine, just remove the ampersand from `&foo[i]`. Note that `[]` already dereferences the pointer, so there is no need for the extra `&`.